# Javascript - Fullcallendar | No se visualiza la hora de comienzo en el calendario

Tags: javascript

En los parámetros o valores del evento se introduce la hora de comienzo, pero en el calendario no se visualiza esa hora. ¿Cómo se debe hacer para que se pueda ver la hora en el evento?
**Ahora mismo se ve "Reunión Grupo2", pero me gustaría que se viera "9:00 Reunión Grupo2".**

Javascript:

```
document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', function() {
        var calendarEl = document.getElementById('calendar');
        var calendar = new FullCalendar.Calendar(calendarEl, {
            
            initialView: 'dayGridMonth',
            //initialView: 'timeGridWeek',
            timeZone: 'local',
            locale: 'es',
            events: [
       
                {
                title: 'Reunión grupo2',
                start: '2021-07-07',
                end: '2021-07-07',
                allDay: 'False',
                startTime: '9:00',
                endTime: '10:00',
                }

            ],
            eventClick: function(info) {
                alert('Event: ' + info.event.title);
                alert('Coordinates: ' + info.jsEvent.pageX + ',' + info.jsEvent.pageY);
                alert('View: ' + info.view.type);
                // change the border color just for fun
                info.el.style.borderColor = 'red';
            }
        });

        var str = calendar.formatDate('2018-09-01', {
            month: 'long',
            year: 'numeric',
            day: 'numeric'
        });
        calendar.render();
    });
```

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Answer (score 0):

No especifícas la versión de FullCalendar que utilizas, pero según la [documentación](https://fullcalendar.io/docs/event-object) sobre el objeto evento, las propiedades `startTime` y `endTime` no existen en la versión 5 (de hecho según lo que observé en las demás versiones, tampoco existen en versiones anteriores). Ya aclarado ese punto, se especifíca que la propiedad `start` debe ser un [Date object](https://fullcalendar.io/docs/date-object), pero al igual que `startStr` puede ser un string con formato ISO8601 (puedes especificar la fecha y hora en el mismo string). Lo mismo aplica para `end`. Entonces tu evento tiene que tener la siguiente estructura:

```javascript
{
  title: "Reunión grupo2",
  start: "2021-07-07 09:00:00",
  end: "2021-07-07 09:30:00"
}
```

Debudo a que incluyes `start` y `end` puedes obviar el especificar `allDay: false` (que por cierto, al ser JS tiene que ser `false` y no `'False'`).

Así mismo, para las vistas *DayGrid* y *TimeGrid* la opción [`displayEventTime`](https://fullcalendar.io/docs/displayEventTime) es `true` por defecto, es decir, siempre mostrará la hora.

```js
document.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded", function () {
  var calendarEl = document.getElementById("calendar");
  var calendar = new FullCalendar.Calendar(calendarEl, {
    initialView: "dayGridMonth",
    //initialView: 'timeGridWeek',
    timeZone: "local",
    locale: "es",
    events: [
      {
        title: "Reunión grupo2",
        start: "2021-07-07 09:00:00",
        end: "2021-07-07 09:30:00",
      }
    ],
    eventClick: function (info) {
      alert("Event: " + info.event.title);
      alert("Event start hour: " + info.event.start.getHours());
      alert("Event end: " + info.event.end);
      alert("Coordinates: " + info.jsEvent.pageX + "," + info.jsEvent.pageY);
      alert("View: " + info.view.type);
      // change the border color just for fun
      info.el.style.borderColor = "red";
    }
  });

  var str = calendar.formatDate("2018-09-01", {
    month: "long",
    year: "numeric",
    day: "numeric"
  });
  calendar.render();
});
```

```html
<link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/fullcalendar@5.8.0/main.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/fullcalendar@5.8.0/main.min.js"></script>
<div id="calendar"></div>
```